# Checking for the Unique Column except the Own Column

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my Rule :

Table Name is : **company_info**

I have only two fields **CompanyID** and **Telephone**

In the update section, i want to check whether the Telephone Number exists for other columns and if the own field have it i don't want to check it. (Currently it checks the own data and returning with Telephone number was taken already).

```
'Telephone'       => 'unique:company_info',
```

Then i tried with the below rule

But i miss in the

```
'Telephone' => 'unique|unique:company_info,CompanyID,'.$companyid)
```

or

```
'Telephone' => 'unique|unique:company_info,Telephone,'.$companyid)
```

or

```
'Telephone' => 'unique|unique:company_info,Telephone,'.$Telephone)
```

Here is my Code :

```
$companyid = Input::get('CompanyID');
$Telephone = Input::get('Telephone');
$rule  =  array(
'Telephone' => 'unique|unique:company_info,CompanyID,'.$companyid
                )
$validator = Validator::make($data,$rule);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $messages = $validator->messages();
         return "0"."||".$messages = $validator->messages()->first('Telephone');
        }
```

While the update query i need to check for the unique rule except the given id

I refered this one http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique

But i am not getting return on `$validator = Validator::make($data,$rule);`

How can i check for the unique value except the own column

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the wrong syntax for unique validation 
it should be

```
'Telephone' => 'unique:company_info,CompanyID,'.$companyid
```

**or**

```
'Telephone' => 'required|unique:company_info,CompanyID,'.$companyid
```

**and not**

```
'Telephone' => 'unique|unique:company_info,CompanyID,'.$companyid
```

Answer (score 1):

Can try this as the [Laravel Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) provides us various features

```
$companyid = Input::get('CompanyID');
$Telephone = Input::get('Telephone');
$data   =   array('companyid'=>$companyid, 'Telephone'=>$Telephone );

//FOR INSERTING NEW DATA
$rule  =  array(
    'Telephone' => 'required|unique:company_info,Telephone,{:id}'
                );
$validator = Validator::make($data,$rule);

//FOR UPDATING AN EXISTING DATA
public static function rule ($id, $merge=[])  { 
    return array_merge(
        [
             'Telephone' => 'required|unique:company_info,Telephone,'.$id,
        ], 
    $merge);
}

$validator = Validator::make($data,self::rule($id));
```

Comment for errors...

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
'Telephone' => 'unique:company_info,Telephone,'.$companyid.', CompanyID';
```

> {rule} =>
>   'unique:{table_name},{unique_column_name},{except_column_value},{except_column_name}'